# Garage door spring/cable drum conundrum

Tags: garage-door, cables

Recently my garage door failed -- one side was not winding up completely, causing the door to slant and driving the other side into the track at the bottom.

There are two springs, and 7-8 years ago *one* of them was replaced (not by me).  This was the side where the door slanted up (so the bottom was pulled into the track). It seemed obvious the other, older spring should be replaced.

The springs are quite large, 32" long with a 1.75" inner diameter.  The closest single spring available to me was slightly bigger -- 2" inner diameter.  I did not think this would be a major problem, especially since the door had never gone up all the way properly; the last segment hung down almost a foot below the entry frame, but since it was still enough to get a car in I didn't worry too much about it.

I am now thinking the springs were always too big.  The cable drums are 4" in diameter, so 12.5" circumference, meaning in order to raise the door 7' they need to rotate 6.75 times Online charts actually say a bit more, based on a 12" diameter and a bit extra to prevent any slackening at the top.

Unfortunately, winding the springs that far resulted in too much lift, and the door would not stay down.  After spending several hours adjusting the springs a quarter turn at a time, I found the most I could wind them was between 5 and 6 complete turns, and then door would not raise far enough with the electric lift, only ~5.5'. I could then manually push it all the way up and once horizontal the electric lift would hold it, but the excess turns given the drums caused the cables to unwind then wrap themselves around the bar, etc., causing the door to jam and I would have to remove the cables, lower the door, and put them back on again, plus rewind the springs.

I see a few solutions to this problem:

- Adding some counter weight to the door, which I would much rather not.
- Get bigger drums, but I think 5" diameter is the ceiling for that which would mean a 15.7" diameter, at 5.5 turns is ~7', barely enough.
- Get smaller springs.

I think the last choice gives me the best chance of actually having the door work properly, ie., go up the whole 8' and end completely horizontal. But I am not sure how much smaller I should go and am looking for some insight.

Comment: Stuff that works in pairs, should be replaced in pairs.  Getting just one spring to replaced the older one now will give the same problem on the other side.  If doing it yourself, these springs can be quite deadly, having an expert setup them up is a good idea.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the door manufacturer and asking them. They're the ones who know what should go with each of their doors.